# JS Reset Button not removing a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```js
function ageInDays() {
    var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born');
    //Subtracts your birthyear from the current year, and multiplys by 365 (365 days in a year)
    var ageInDayss = (2021 - birthYear) * 365 ;
    //Creates a h1 element
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    //Creates the text 'you are (age in days) days old' 
    var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInDayss + ' days old ');
    //The setAttribute() method adds the specified attribute to an element, and gives it the specified value
    h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDayss');
    //The appendChild() method appends (adds) a node as the last child of a node
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    //The Document method getElementById() returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string
    document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
    
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementsById('ageInDays').remove();
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-1">
        <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days </h2>
        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click Me</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="static/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was following a tutorial on how to calculate your age in days using HTML, CSS and Javascript. I managed to get the 'Click Me' button to work and calculate my age in days. However, when it came to the red 'Reset' button it just wouldn't work. It just won't work, please help!

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do not just paste in a YouTube url as it has several disadvantages. Namely you're making the people trying to help you spend a lot more of their free time for you than needed. It can also be seen as you're just trying to get views and likes on a video etc. Get the code part that isn't working as supposed to and put it in your question. Explain what it's supposed to do and any errors you're getting in your browser console.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Well it is because ```reset``` is a inbuilt feature of ```input``` which is used to ```reset``` any value ```input``` but it can't remove any value you enter in ```input``` using a ```function``` .  

So you have to add a extra ```function``` when ```reset``` is clicked and remove the function .  
I was also facing this problem and get it by trying different hard ways

Comment: Can you send the code on how to do that as I am a beginner at js. This is the code function                                                                                               
  reset() {
    document.getElementsById('ageInDays').remove();
}

Comment: @Aaron-00-00: When you run the code in the above snippet, the error message tells you what's wrong.  In your own browser always check the development console for errors.

Comment: I get this error "message": "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function",

Comment: That's because [`document.getElementsById` is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Also, `(2021 - birthYear) * 365` is not your age in days.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo (extra and missing 's') in your code :

```
h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDayss'); // double s
```

and

```
document.getElementsById('ageInDays').remove(); // single s
```

also document.getElement**s**ById => getElementById

```js
function ageInDays() {
    var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born');
    //Subtracts your birthyear from the current year, and multiplys by 365 (365 days in a year)
    var ageInDayss = (2021 - birthYear) * 365 ;
    //Creates a h1 element
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    //Creates the text 'you are (age in days) days old' 
    var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInDayss + ' days old ');
    //The setAttribute() method adds the specified attribute to an element, and gives it the specified value
    h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
    //The appendChild() method appends (adds) a node as the last child of a node
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    //The Document method getElementById() returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string
    document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
    
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-1">
        <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days </h2>
        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click Me</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="static/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```